# How to let a thread communicate with another activity thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

i'm beginning to learn android, i meet a problem in my project,

in my application,i create a background thread which get data from remote server by UDP,
in this thread ,i will  parse the data  and distribute the message to different activity to process, so i don't know weather is there a mechanism to handle this problem.

thanks for your answer

Comment: Could you provide a few more details - are you asking how to pass data from a background thread to another activity, or how to pass data from a background thread to the activity that created the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this article about [painless threading in android](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html), and pick a solution that best fits for you.

If you retrieve data from the server repeatedly, maybe you should go with a `Service` - `Handler` solution, but `AsyncTask` seams to be the easiest for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go through the dev guide as suggested by @UBM. Also, if you are looking for different threading constructs and communication, I would strongly recommend you to look at a series of articles on Android threading constructs starting with this [article](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-1-ui.html).