# Unexpected behavior by if-else statement

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

I have the following `if-else` statement that are triggered after clicking a button

```
if (!rf.registerUser(url,
    username.getText().toString(), phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
    materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), registrationjson)) {

// below registeringError is to show an alert when error occurs

    rf.registeringError(v.getContext(), warning, getResources().getString(R.string.registeringError));
    System.out.println("Failure!");


} else if (rf.registerUser(url,
     username.getText().toString(), phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
     materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), registrationjson)) {

// below registrationSuccess method is to show an alert after successful registration

     rf.registrationSuccess(v.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.congrats),
     getResources().getString(R.string.successfull_registration));

     System.out.println("Success!");
}
```

below is registerUser method code

```
 public boolean registerUser(String uri, String username, String phone, String state, String password, registrationJson registrationjson) {
        OkHttpClient client;
        RequestBody body;

        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        registrationjson.setUsername(username);
        registrationjson.setPhone(phone);
        registrationjson.setState(state);
        registrationjson.setPassword(password);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        final String jsonFromform = gson.toJson(registrationjson);

        client = new OkHttpClient();
        body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonFromform);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(uri)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failure!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                switch (response.code()){
                    case 400:
                        changeStatusFalse(); // change status boolean to false
                    case 200:
                        changeStatusTrue(); //change status boolean to true
                }
            }

        });
        return status; // return status
    }
```

the problem am facing is that when I fill the registration form and press the button (expecting everything to work fine) I get the `registeringError` alert and then I press the button again without closing the screen, I get the `registrationSuccess` alert

I tried using `if-else` in `registerUser` instead of `switch statement`.

WIERD THING: I tried to change the `return` from `return status` to `return true`. the `registeringError` alert got executed first, then after pressing the button again `successRegistration` got executed.

NOTE: when I press the button, error alert shows in a nanosecond (to describe how fast it is) before the server logs the success message, but am not really sure if this is actually the problem since the code that checks the status of the response is inside `onResponse` method

Comment: registerUser this function will always give false as original request to server  is not yet completed (it's in queue.) , your function is returning immediately which is why you are getting error message pop up.

Comment: @Vijay thanks for clarification, but how can I make the function wait for the server response?

Comment: @Vijay is it because the method is inside non-activity class? and if yes, do you know how to make it function without moving the code to the activity class?

Comment: You can use a communication api like https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for sending a message to your registered activity when you get the response from the server or you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684548/how-to-let-a-thread-communicate-with-another-activity-thread